# SQL query about self join

Tags: sql, db2

I have a sql in db2 as below:

```
SELECT  distinct KEY_COL, MY_TYPE1,
CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'ONE' THEN COL1 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL1, 
CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'ONE' THEN COL2 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL2, 
CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'TWO' THEN COL1 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL3, 
CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'TWO' THEN COL2  ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL4 
FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
```

As clear from above query, based on `MY_TYPE2` colums in `MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE`, the new column values are decided.

If the `MY_TYPE2` is one, `col1` and `col2` goes to `newcol1` and `newcol2` respectively for given key and `MY_TYPE1` column. But if the `MY_TYPE2` is two for same key and `MY_TYPE1`, then `col1` and `col2` goes to `newcol3` and `newcol4`.

The output table looks something like below:

```
KEY_COL | MY_TYPE1 | NEWCOL1 | NEWCOL2 | NEWCOL3 | NEWCOL4
=========================================================
 1          T1         1         2
 1          T1                              4          3
 1          T2         2         3                    
 1          T2                              4          1
 ========================================================
```

However, I want a single row based on MY_TYPE1 column as below:

```
 KEY_COL | MY_TYPE1 | NEWCOL1 | NEWCOL2 | NEWCOL3 | NEWCOL4
 =========================================================
 1          T1         1         2          4          3
 1          T2         2         3          4          1
 ========================================================
```

How to modify the query to achieve above result ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That `DISTINCT` isn't going to do anything, assuming that you have unique rows to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select key_col, my_type1, max(newcol1), max(newcol2), max(newcol3), max(newcol4) 
from 
(
    SELECT  distinct KEY_COL, MY_TYPE1,
    CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'ONE' THEN COL1 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL1, 
    CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'ONE' THEN COL2 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL2, 
    CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'TWO' THEN COL1 ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL3, 
    CASE WHEN MY_TYPE2 = 'TWO' THEN COL2  ELSE '' END AS NEWCOL4 
    FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
) definedTable
group by key_col, my_type1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select KEY_COL ,max(MY_TYPE1),max(NEWCOL1),max(NEWCOL2),max(NEWCOL3),max(NEWCOL4)
from table
group by KEY_COL
```

Comment: (not downvoter... but -) For completeness sake, you should probably put in the rest of the query.